# how to sort html javascripts post cards side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a html post card code like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFqRU.jpg), how to sort cards to the side? side by side i mean..

this is full code:

```
<main class="main-area">

        <div class="centered">

            <section class="cards">
              {% for post in paginator.posts %}

                <article class="card">
                    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                        </div><!-- .card-content -->
                        <picture class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="https://d4mucfpksywv.cloudfront.net/research-covers/science-of-ai/gradient.jpg" alt="A banana that looks like a bird">
                        </picture>
                    </a>
                </article><!-- .card -->
            </section><!-- .cards -->
           {% endfor %}
        </div><!-- .centered -->

    </main>
```

Comment: you want them horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: I think that the endfor should be before the end of the section

Comment: yes. thankyou, i found it @mohameddrira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see your css but the default css for an article tag is "block". This is the reason why the postcards are aligned vertically.

```css
.card{ 
  display: inline
}
```

This line would fix it. But since that probably would cause some ugly design I would recommend using flex.

```css
.cards{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

There are even more options to design your "flex" flow like "justify-content/align-items". 
Also I think mohameddrira is right and your {% endfor %} is at the wrong point in your code  causing some trouble.

Comment: this is my css: `.cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }

.card {
    flex: 1 0 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 1rem .5em;
}`

Comment: You missed setting the directions of your flex. I used "flex-flow" (row wrap) which combines "flex-direction" (row) and "flex-wrap" (wrap).